# Android GPS V2 Tutorial Issue -Google Maps

Tags: java, android, api, gps, maps

I have been working with this tutorial [http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/]

Its GPS Map Location App that gets your location, or nearby location. I and many others have tested this and there seems to be an error as the app just crashes.
I have changed the SHA1 Fingerprint and Google API Key. 
There are no errors in the code, i have imported the google play store.

Does anyone have any ideas on this, I have looked at the comments on the website and allot of users are having the same problem.
Here is LogCat:

```
03-26 03:43:53.835: W/dalvikvm(15048): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x42014700)
03-26 03:43:53.845: E/AndroidRuntime(15048): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-26 03:43:53.845: E/AndroidRuntime(15048): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{info.androidhive.googlemapsv2/info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
03-26 03:43:53.845: E/AndroidRuntime(15048):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
03-26 03:43:53.845: E/AndroidRuntime(15048):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
03-26 03:43:53.845: E/AndroidRuntime(15048):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
03-26 03:43:53.845: E/AndroidRuntime(15048):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
03-26 03:43:53.845: E/AndroidRuntime(15048):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-26 03:43:53.845: E/AndroidRuntime(15048):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
03-26 03:43:53.845: E/AndroidRuntime(15048):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
03-26 03:43:53.845: E/AndroidRuntime(15048):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-26 03:43:53.845: E/AndroidRuntime(15048):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-26 03:43:53.845: E/AndroidRuntime(15048):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
03-26 03:43:53.845: E/AndroidRuntime(15048):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
03-26 03:43:53.845: E/AndroidRuntime(15048):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-26 03:43:53.845: E/AndroidRuntime(15048): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
03-26 03:43:53.845: E/AndroidRuntime(15048):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:719)
03-26 03:43:53.845: E/AndroidRuntime(15048):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
03-26 03:43:53.845: E/AndroidRuntime(15048):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
03-26 03:43:53.845: E/AndroidRuntime(15048):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
03-26 03:43:53.845: E/AndroidRuntime(15048):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
03-26 03:43:53.845: E/AndroidRuntime(15048):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:361)
03-26 03:43:53.845: E/AndroidRuntime(15048):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1956)
03-26 03:43:53.845: E/AndroidRuntime(15048):    at info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
03-26 03:43:53.845: E/AndroidRuntime(15048):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
03-26 03:43:53.845: E/AndroidRuntime(15048):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
03-26 03:43:53.845: E/AndroidRuntime(15048):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
03-26 03:43:53.845: E/AndroidRuntime(15048):    ... 11 more
03-26 03:43:53.845: E/AndroidRuntime(15048): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A required meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not exist.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
03-26 03:43:53.845: E/AndroidRuntime(15048):    at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.t(Unknown Source)
03-26 03:43:53.845: E/AndroidRuntime(15048):    at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
03-26 03:43:53.845: E/AndroidRuntime(15048):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.B(Unknown Source)
03-26 03:43:53.845: E/AndroidRuntime(15048):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.A(Unknown Source)
03-26 03:43:53.845: E/AndroidRuntime(15048):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
03-26 03:43:53.845: E/AndroidRuntime(15048):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.gW(Unknown Source)
03-26 03:43:53.845: E/AndroidRuntime(15048):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)
03-26 03:43:53.845: E/AndroidRuntime(15048):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
03-26 03:43:53.845: E/AndroidRuntime(15048):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source)
03-26 03:43:53.845: E/AndroidRuntime(15048):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
03-26 03:43:53.845: E/AndroidRuntime(15048):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4965)
03-26 03:43:53.845: E/AndroidRuntime(15048):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:695)
03-26 03:43:53.845: E/AndroidRuntime(15048):    ... 21 more
```

Comment: are you trying in emulator?

Comment: Please Upload the code of your AndroidManifest.xml file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logcat clearly said:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A required meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not exist.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
 03-26 03:43:53.845: E/AndroidRuntime(15048):    at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.t(Unknown Source)
 03-26 03:43:53.845: E/AndroidRuntime(15048):    at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAv
```

**Add the Google Play services version to your app's manifest**

> Edit your application's AndroidManifest.xml file, and add the
>   following declaration within the element. This embeds the version of
>   Google Play services that the app was compiled with.

You just need to add `<meta-data>` under `<application>` tag into your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
....<application>
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"  
 android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

This is because latest google play services requires a version name, which is to be mentioned using `<meta-data .. />` inside `AndroidManifest.xml`

build your **manifest.xml** like:

```
....<application>
  ..............
  <meta-data
  android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
  android:value="APIKEY" />

  <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"  
  android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

   </application>
```

Comment: <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:v*MY KEY*" />
        
    </application>      I already have the metadata in application

Comment: also add another `<meta-data>` tag as per my answer this is becoz latest services required to mention a Version Value in `manifest.xml`

Comment: Do you have any idea how I would get an address from my current location and store it in a string

Comment: using `GeoCoder` you can do this.